# What is the best data mining method for vehicle search?

Tags: data-mining, site-mining

I'm trying to build a search engine that goes through online vehicle classifieds such as Oodle, eBay motors, and craigslist. I also have a large database of standard vehicle names and specifications about them. What I would like to do is for each record that I find through the classified site, be able to determine exactly what vehicle  model, style it is (from my database). For example, a standard name for a ford truck in my db is:
2003 Ford F150.

However on classified sites, people might refer to is as: "2003 Ford F 150" or "2003 Ford f-150" or "03 Ford truck 150". Is there an effective data mining/text classification algorithm to be able to normalize these texts to the standard name above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to match the found string against your database records.

Another (probably better) idea is to tokenize the strings and use a [term vector model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) for the vehicle names. This way you can use cosine similarity to find relevant matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna develop a whole search engine intended to scale in both, usage and size, you will need something robust to support your queries.

If you're gonna used edit distance, [Bed-trees](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~comad/2010/pdf/SIGMOD%20Highlight%20Session/sigmod10-bed-slides.pdf) provide a good alternative for your index structure. Another good approach, depending on the size of your dataset, is to use a [Levenshtein automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata). Levenshtein automatas are also great at providing auto-complete functionalities, which you may need since you're developing a search engine.

Another approach to edit distance is to use n-grams combined with Jaccard index. For this approach you can use [Minhash + LSH](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs246/slides/03-lsh.pdf). Also, you can use Jaccard as a distance metric (1 - Jaccard index) which respects the triangle inequality, thus, can be used in a metric tree such as a [VP-tree](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=130).

One of these approaches will certainly help you.